# Create multiple rows from a cell value in R

Tags: r, dataframe, formatting

I am working on one formatting related use case in R where I have a dataframe like below created with the R code

```
usecase <- data.frame(ID = 1:3,Value = c("A | B | C","D | E | F | G","H | J"))
```

[image]->CURRENT TABLE

I want table to be created like below and the values are not static it can vary like for ID 1 we have 3 values, ID 2 has 4 and so on.And the special character between values are pipe symbol "|"

[image] -> EXPECTED OUTPUT

Comment: 1) `usecase <- data.frame(ID = 1:3,Value = c("A | B | C","D | E | F | G","H | J"))`
2) `usecase`

3) `usecase$Value <- gsub(" [|] ","", usecase$Value)`
4) `usecase`

5) `newID <- rep(usecase$ID, c(nchar(usecase$Value)))`
6) `newID`


7) `newValue <- unlist(strsplit(usecase$Value, split = ""))`
8) `new_usecase <- data.frame(newID, newValue)`
9) `new_usecase`